# Data matching technique

Tags: matching

I have a database of different clients and I know from which countries these customers source their good from. E.g. XZY company sources 80% of the goods from China 10% from India and 10% from Russia. ABC company sources 70% of the goods from Brazil 20% from India and 10% from US.

I am looking for an easy way to assign proximity scores to different clients based on their sourcing strategy - how similar they are?

Another way it would be to assign clients to different clusters based on these scores - like K-Mean

Any additional suggestions?

Comment: What would be the purpose of these scores?

Comment: To match observations in my database with observations in an external database based on their sourcing decision.